# Corrupted audio file received from POST REQUESTs in a Flask Application

Tags: flask, python-requests

This is my POST Request code:

`import requests
import os

URL="http://localhost:5005/predict"

TEST_AUDIO_FILE_PATH = "3.wav"

if **name** == "**main**" :

```
audio_file = open(TEST_AUDIO_FILE_PATH, "rb")

values = {"file": audio_file}
response = requests.post(URL,files=values)
data = response

print(data)`
```

This is the receiver code ( Its just partial code only  but having error in this part ):

`

app.route('/predict', methods=['GET','POST'])

def get_speech_to_text_conversion():

```
input_file = request.files["file"]

input_data = input_file.read()
print("input data:", input_data)
file_name = f'C:/Users/Aris/Documents/Voice_to_Text/User_Input/{input_file.filename}'

input_file.save(file_name)
dataset = load_dataset("audiofolder", data_files=file_name, split="train")
```

`

I am trying to receive the file in a POST Request and save it in my folder. Its saving as a corrupted file and not open to play this file.

What went wrong in the sender or receiver part?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `file.read()` to read the entire data from the file-like object, the pointer moves to the end of the file. If you then try to save the data using `file.save(path)`, the pointer is still at the end of the file and no data is written. Use `file.seek(0)` to reset the pointer to the beginning and read the data again.

```
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os

app.post('/predict')
def get_speech_to_text_conversion():
    file = request.files['file']

    data = file.read()
    print('input data:', data)
    
    file.seek(0) # Jump back to the beginning.

    path = os.path.join(
        app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 
        secure_filename(file.filename)
    )
    file.save(path)

    # ...
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.  I used your code to save the file but its still saving with 0 bytes in the uploaded folder.